# How to delete an element from custom list type in c++?

Tags: c++, stl

I am trying to implement adjacency list in C++. I want to write a function to delete an edge from a vertex.

Refer following code.

```
class edge {
private:
    int destinationVertex;     /*!< ::vertex.id of destination vertex in graph */
public:
    /**
     * Counstructor for edge.
     */
    edge (int ver) : destinationVertex(ver) {
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& a, edge const& e) {
        return a << e.destinationVertex;
    }

    /** @return value of ::destinationVertex */
    int getDestinationVertex() {
        return destinationVertex;
    }

    ~edge();
};

class graph;

class vertex {
    friend class graph;
    /** id of the vertex */
    int id;
    /** list of destinations */
    std::list<edge> list;

public:
    /**
     * Counstructor that creates an new empty vertex.
     */
    vertex(int id) : id(id)
    {
    }

    /**
     * @brief Overloading for << operator.
     * @details friend function that overloads the << operator for vertex
     *          class and defines a printing behaviour.
     */
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, vertex const& v) {
        s << v.id << "->";
        std::copy(v.list.begin(), v.list.end(), std::ostream_iterator<edge>(s, ","));
        return s;
    }

    /**
     * Linear search for a in list of edges of the vertex.
     * @param  a value to search
     * @return   true if element matches, else false
     */

    bool find(int a) {
        for(std::list<edge>::iterator it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it)
        {
            if((*it).getDestinationVertex() == a)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Returns degree of a vertex.
     * @return number of edges in vertex
     */
    int deg() {
        return list.size();
    }

    void removeEdge(const int id) {
        /// How do i use the remove function of list to delete elements
        /// Any other way to write this function

    }
};
```

See the `vertex.removeEdge(...)`. I have tried using

```
list.remove(id);
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Link to repository https://github.com/piyushdivyankar1994/graph-theory.git

Answer (score 1):

`std::list::remove()` removes all items that match a specified value. Your `edge` class can be constructed from an `int` value, but it has no comparison operators that `std::list::remove()` can use to compare `edge` objects for equality. You need to implement those operators, or else use `std::list::remove_if()` instead so you can do the comparisons using a predicate function/lambda.

On the other hand, if the `int` value that is being passed to `vertex::removeEdge()` represents the same kind of value that is being passed to `vertex::find()`, then you could just use the same looping logic in `removeEdge()` that you already have in `find()`.  Use `std::list::erase()` to remove an item by iterator.

BTW, you might consider re-writing `vertex::find()` to use `std::find_if()` with a predicate, instead of using a manual loop.

Comment: I tried doing what you suggested but it gives a segmentation fault. code 
`void removeEdge(const int a) {
        std::list<edge>::iterator k = findIterator(a);
        list.erase(k);
    }`
Valgrind says
`==23912== Invalid read of size 8
==23912==    at 0x401FA9: std::_List_iterator<edge>::operator++()`
@remy

Comment: @PiyushDivyankar you did not show what `findIterator()` does, and you are not checking if `k` points to a valid item before passing it to `erase()`.